# Read JSON from AJAX in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

Im having issues with a JSON File that im trying to send to my ASP.NET

I want to read the file, output it and filter other functions with it later accordingly.

**My script looks something like this:**

```
<script>

var NetworkValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("NetworkValues"));
var arpValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("arpValues"));
var addrValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("addrValues"));
var fsckValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("fsckValues"));
var vmstatValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("vmstatValues"));
var freeValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("freeValues"));
var ServiceValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ServiceValues"));
var ProcessValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ProcessValues"));
var topValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("topValues"));
var PortValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("PortValues"));

function sendValues()
    {var NetworkOutput = NetworkValues;
var arpOutput = arpValues;
var addrOutput = addrValues;
var fsckOutput = fsckValues;
var vmstatOutput = vmstatValues;
var freeOutput = freeValues;
var serviceOutput = ServiceValues;
var processOutput = ProcessValues;
var topOutput = topValues;
var PortOutput = PortValues;

var message = document.getElementById('message');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "api/FilterSubmit",
        data: 
        {
        NetworkOutput: NetworkOutput,
        arpOutput: arpOutput,
        addrOutput: addrOutput,
        fsckOutput: fsckOutput,
        vmstatOutput: vmstatOutput,
        freeOutput: freeOutput,
        serviceOutput: serviceOutput,
        processOutput: processOutput,
        topOutput: topOutput,
        PortOutput : PortOutput
        },
    success: function(result) 
        {
            message.innerHTML = 'success!' 
            console.log(NetworkOutput)   
            console.log(arpOutput) 
            console.log(addrOutput)   
            console.log(fsckOutput)  
            console.log(vmstatOutput)  
            console.log(freeOutput) 
            console.log(processOutput)
            console.log(serviceOutput)
            console.log(topOutput)
            console.log(PortOutput)
                                                       
        },
        error: function(err) 
        {
       message.innerHTML = 'failed!'
        }
    })
    }
```

**What ive been trying inside the controller:**
*(src: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/sending-and-receiving-json-using-httpclient-with-system-net-http-json)*

```
using AspNetCore.MariaDB.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http.Json;
using System.Reflection.Metadata.Ecma335;


namespace AspNetCore.MariaDB.Controllers
{
    public class Buttoncontroller : Controller
    {

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/FilterSubmit")]

        public IActionResult ButtonClickSub()
        {
            static async Task<FilteredScripts> GetJsonHttpClient(string uri, HttpClient httpClient)
            {
                try
                {
                    return await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<FilteredScripts>(uri);
                }
                catch (HttpRequestException) // Non success
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An error occurred.");
                }
                catch (NotSupportedException) // When content type is not valid
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The content type is not supported.");
                }


                return null;
            }
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

```
private static async Task<User> GetJsonFromContent(string uri, HttpClient httpClient)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("some-header", "some-value");

    using var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // perhaps check some headers before deserialising

        try
        {
            return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<User>();
        }
        catch (NotSupportedException) // When content type is not valid
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The content type is not supported.");
        }
        catch (JsonException) // Invalid JSON
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid JSON.");
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: You have a static method _inside_ a non-static method ... that cannot be right. Does that even compile?

Comment: yes it does, the only real warning im getting is that GetJsonHttpClient is never used

Comment: In your ajax success callback, you're not even using result which will contain your json object.

Comment: function submitFunc1() {
                    var message = document.getElementById('message');
                    var btn = document.getElementById('DelButton');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "api/delete",
                        data: {
                            btn: btn.value
                        },
                        success: function(result) {         
                            message.innerHTML = 'success!'
                        },
here for example,  I get the desired output without return though

Comment: _" warning im getting is that GetJsonHttpClient is never used"_ - yes, because it isn't.

Comment: _Im having issues_ - What issues?

Comment: Please clarify the problem.

Comment: I want to read the file in ASP
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please re-read the [mre] guidance on posting code and make sure there is no extra code included in the question. I.e. the `ButtonClickSub` contains far too much code for what it is doing - `public IActionResult ButtonClickSub() => Ok();` will do exactly the same without all that unused nested function. Also for creating data - inline hardcoded  values are much better than reading them from somewhere, you also likely need one or two instead of dozen to *demonstrate* the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is I forgot to specifically send a proper JSON back to .NET and have Memory stream actually try to read it:

**JavaScript:**

```js
 

function sendValues() {
 var data123 = JSON.stringify({
        NetworkOutput: NetworkOutput,
        arpOutput: arpOutput,
        addrOutput: addrOutput,
        fsckOutput: fsckOutput,
        vmstatOutput: vmstatOutput,
        freeOutput: freeOutput,
        serviceOutput: serviceOutput,
        processOutput: processOutput,
        topOutput: topOutput,
        PortOutput: PortOutput
      });

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "api/FilterSubmit",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: data123
        success: ...
        err: ...
        })
```

**Controller:**

```
    public class FilterSubmitData
 {
     public string[] NetworkOutput { get; set; }
     public string[] arpOutput { get; set; }
     public string[] addrOutput { get; set; }
     public string[] fsckOutput { get; set; }
     public string[] vmstatOutput { get; set; }
     public string[] freeOutput { get; set; }
     public string[] serviceOutput { get; set; }
     public string[] processOutput { get; set; }
     public string[] topOutput { get; set; }
     public string[] PortOutput { get; set; }
    
 }

    [HttpPost]
[Route("api/FilterSubmit")]
public async Task<IActionResult> StreamWithNewtonsoftJson()
{
    FilterSubmitData data;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await Request.Body.CopyToAsync(ms);
        using var streamMs = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
        using var streamReader = new StreamReader(streamMs);
        using var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader);
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        data = serializer.Deserialize<FilterSubmitData>(jsonReader);
    }

    


    return Ok();
}
```